# Randomize material on procedural cubes in new "Fields" Geo nodes in 3.0 alpha

Tags: geometry-nodes

Below is an example setup of my geo nodes.
How can add a random material to faces of each cube with latest geo nodes fields update?

[image]

Comment: 3.0 Is still under development, try with a stable version

Answer (score 0):

Using instance collection worked

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does the node tree add a random material for each face ?

Comment: Added image showing instance collection